# how to run 2 asynchronous timers implemented in a class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I want the second timer to start working half a second after the second one, but the moment the second timer starts working, the terminal displays something completely different from what I want. If it does not impose restrictions before executing the second timer, then they both work as they should

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class print{
public:
    print(boost::asio::io_context& io) : timer_(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1)), count_(0){
        timer_.async_wait(std::bind(&print::printer, this));
    }

    void printer(){
        if(count_ < 5){
            std::cout << count_ << "\n";
            ++count_;

            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expiry() + boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1));
            timer_.async_wait(std::bind(&print::printer, this));
        }
    }

    ~print(){
        std::cout << "Last num " << count_ << "\n";
    }
private:
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
    int count_;
};

int main(){
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    
    print p(io);

    boost::asio::steady_timer t(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(2));
    t.async_wait([&io](const boost::system::error_code& ec){
        if(!ec){
            print pp(io);
        }
    });

    io.run();   
}
```

that's what the terminal outputs

```
0,
1,
Last num 0,
2,
3,
4,
Last num 5.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second timer `pp` is a local variable. It is destructed immediately.

Therefore the async operation is using a deleted instance and invoked [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should probably be detecting cancellation by actually receiving `error_code` in the completion handler. The `std::bind` expression silently drops it for you, now.

You can use dynamic allocation of some sort. I also strongly suggest separating and generalizing the notion of an interval timer and the action that is executed:

```
struct Timer {
    using Callback = std::function<bool()>;

    Timer(asio::any_io_executor ex, duration d, Callback cb)
        : timer_(ex, d)
        , interval_(d)
        , cb_(std::move(cb)) { do_loop(); }

  private:
    asio::steady_timer timer_;
    duration           interval_;
    Callback           cb_;

    void do_loop() {
        timer_.async_wait(bind(&Timer::on_tick, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void on_tick(error_code ec) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cerr << "Warning: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        } else if (cb_()) {
            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expiry() + interval_);
            do_loop();
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can use it like:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;
using duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;

struct Timer {
    using Callback = std::function<bool()>;

    Timer(asio::any_io_executor ex, duration d, Callback cb)
        : timer_(ex, d)
        , interval_(d)
        , cb_(std::move(cb)) { do_loop(); }

  private:
    asio::steady_timer timer_;
    duration           interval_;
    Callback           cb_;

    void do_loop() {
        timer_.async_wait(bind(&Timer::on_tick, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void on_tick(error_code ec) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cerr << "Warning: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        } else if (cb_()) {
            timer_.expires_at(timer_.expiry() + interval_);
            do_loop();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context io;
    auto ex = io.get_executor();

    auto printer = [](std::string_view name) {
        return [name, count_ = 0]() mutable {
            bool more = count_ < 5;
            std::cout << "Printer " << quoted(name) << (more ? " " : " Last num ") << count_ << "\n";
            ++count_;
            return more;
        };
    };

    std::optional<Timer> second;

    Timer first(ex, 1s, printer("First"));
    Timer delay(ex, 1500ms, [&] {
        second.emplace(ex, 1s, printer("Second"));
        return false;
    });

    io.run();
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64b68fc304a265f2)**

Which prints:

```
Printer "First" 0
Printer "First" 1
Printer "Second" 0
Printer "First" 2
Printer "Second" 1
Printer "First" 3
Printer "Second" 2
Printer "First" 4
Printer "Second" 3
Printer "First" Last num 5
Printer "Second" 4
Printer "Second" Last num 5
```

Or more interactively:

[image]

Comment: As a bonus: full dynamic allocation, running many secondary timers at varying intervals, with `enable_shared_from_this` tracking the lifetime: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdc9032acd3854c0

Comment: thank you very much, although it is very difficult and incomprehensible for me, I am very bad at Boost.Asio :)

Comment: If you're learning and you can use C++20, consider going C++20 coroutines. It really simplifies lifetime management. Here's the exact same demo as in my previous comment but with coroutines: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df31902fdf756746